# Jquery Focusing another element on blur is not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, input, focus

I am trying to focus another input element on one input`s blur event. But its not working.

```
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>


$("input:last").on("blur",function(e){
   $("input:first").focus();
})
```

the cursor is not present in the element. So i am not able to type anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/7foref2g/

Comment: Can you add your HTML code also

Comment: works fine in chrome

Comment: Maybe because first `input` is not textbox. Try [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7foref2g/2/)

Comment: Works just fine in Chrome.  What browser and version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't make it work for FF. See this `jQuery` bug ticket [FIREFOX FOCUS AND BLUR EVENTS NOT FIRING WHEN CALLING FOCUS() AND BLUR()](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13363) and `FireFox` one [Bug 53579 - calling this.blur() in onfocus handler or this.focus() in an onblur handler do not work](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53579)

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked on Firefox desktop. But didn't work in Firefox mobile.